# How to skip first xml element group (Header Row)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Below is my below XML snippet . I receive full headers in first group and my data starts from 2nd element group on wards. Here how can I skip first group ? Like I need to avoid first row elements and needs to use from 2nd row elements. Can some body shed some light , how can I achieve this by XSLT ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
<row>
    <Empl-Id>Empl Id</Empl-Id>
    <Company>Company</Company>
    <firstname>firstname</firstname>
    <lastname>lastname</lastname>
    <Goal-Amount>Goal Amount</Goal-Amount>  
</row>
<row>
    <Empl-Id>0111</Empl-Id>
    <Company>A11</Company>
    <firstname>Jumn</firstname>
    <lastname>Henrry</lastname>
    <Goal-Amount>100</Goal-Amount>  
</row>
<row>
    <Empl-Id>0112</Empl-Id>
    <Company>A12</Company>
    <firstname>Jumn2</firstname>
    <lastname>Henrry2</lastname>
    <Goal-Amount>120t</Goal-Amount> 
</row>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use empty element of for the first row `/root/row[1]`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/row[1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**your output like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

    <row>
        <Empl-Id>0111</Empl-Id>
        <Company>A11</Company>
        <firstname>Jumn</firstname>
        <lastname>Henrry</lastname>
        <Goal-Amount>100</Goal-Amount>  
    </row>
    <row>
        <Empl-Id>0112</Empl-Id>
        <Company>A12</Company>
        <firstname>Jumn2</firstname>
        <lastname>Henrry2</lastname>
        <Goal-Amount>120t</Goal-Amount> 
    </row>
</root>
```

See mentioned link:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKww

Answer (score 1):

If you select or process `/root/row[position() gt 1]` you select or process only the `row` elements starting from the second position. `tail(/root/row)` or `subsequence(/root/row, 2)` or other options in XPath.

In the context of XSLT, depending on how your remaining XSLT looks, it might also suffice to use an empty template `<xsl:template match="root/row[1]"/>` to ensure the first `row` doesn't produce any output.